# Auto cleanup querystore not working

Tags: sql-server-2016, query-store

We have a SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU7 Enterprise server where we enabled the query store on a database. This is a highly used database.
The `Max Size` has been set to 200MB and `Stale Query Threshold` is 1 day. 
I've used `sys.database_query_store_options` to check the properties of the query store and everything works perfect as long as `the current_storage_size_mb` stays under the 200MB. 
I've set `Size Based Cleanup Mode` to Auto but no cleanup happens, normally a cleanup should be triggered when the query store is 90% full. What happens  next is that the query store goes into readonly mode because there is no available space left.
I've tried changing `Query Store Capture Mode` to Auto but nothings changes.
If I then change `Stale Query Threshold` to 30 days the `actual_state_desc` changes to READ_WRITE and the query store starts capturing again. The `current_storage_size_mb` just becomes higher than the `max_storage_size_mb` and after a while the `actual_state_desc` goes back to READ_ONLY.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago I updated the server to SQL Server 2016 SP2 and the problem disappeared. Now when the querystore hits 90% it is cleaned up till it reaches 80%.

I don't know if SP2 was the solution or was it the restart of the SQL Service due to the update.